# Get value of field attached to the file entity in a view

Tags: views, entities

I extended the file entity of type video, which ships with the media/file_entity module, with an extra field "tags". How can i get the values of this attached field in views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to add a relationship with your file field, then the fields on your file entity should be available when adding fields to your view.

Comment: Yes, that's it!